# safari developer tools How do I watch expressions from iframe?

Tags: javascript, safari, expression, watch, developer-tools

I have some content to debug in an iframe.

I cant seem to get Safari developer tool to recognize any scripts in an iframe. Let's say I want to Watch Expressions in the iframe. I add a variable to "Watched Expressions" from the iframe in the scripts tab of Safari Developer tools - yet the values always show up as '**Error**'

Using Safari Developer Tools - How do I get the Watched Expressions to work for variables an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Safari are you using? I am using its 6.0.4th version. Well even I could not find the option to add watch expressions but **at the bottom of the debugging window** there is one more **down arrow icon near continue script execution icon**. **Clicking on the icon you will get one console and you can see the value of the expressions** you are interested in. Hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the icon in the top right corner of the debugger window (The icon next to "{}" "T" "C"). "Scope Chain" should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

It's March 2015 and the add watch expression feature is not yet present in Safari. Use Google Chrome instead.

Comment: how is this an answer? what if you're debugging an iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Safari -> Develop -> Select the device -> Web inspector will get opens

In the menu tabs close the debugger tab and again open it.

It worked for me, but didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `dev tools`

Go to the `debugger` (to see your source code/js)

Open the details sidebar (right sidebar) / `cmd + alt + 0`

In the details sidebar:

- choose `Scope chain`
- click the `+` to add a watch
- write the name of your watch

Done!

[image]